# why sfinae overload is not resolved

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, sfinae

This version works fine:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename U = T>
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,A>::value>::type
        bar() { std::cout << "1" << std::endl; }

    template<typename U = T> 
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,B>::value>::type
        bar() { std::cout << "2" << std::endl; }
};
```

This version fails:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo2
{
    template<typename U = T, typename V = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,A>::value>::type >
        V bar() { std::cout << "1" << std::endl; }

    template<typename U = T, typename V = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,B>::value>::type >
        V bar() { std::cout << "2" << std::endl; }
};
```

with:

> error: 'template template V Foo2::bar()' cannot be overloaded with 'template template V Foo2::bar()'

The difference between both versions is in the first I use the expression directly, in the second one I create a template default parameter and use that one as return type.

What is the reason to fail in the second example?

Comment: Default template parameter values are not part of function signature

Comment: There is even a note about this common mistake in [`std::enable_if` doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in the case#2, the two `bar` are considered to be equivalent. When [consider whether two function templates are equivalent or not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading), the default template parameters are ignored; they're not the part of function template signature. So they're considered as

```
template<typename U, typename V>
V bar() { std::cout << "1" << std::endl; }

template<typename U, typename V>
V bar() { std::cout << "2" << std::endl; }
```

As you can see, they're equivalent in fact.

(emphasis mine)

> Two function templates are considered equivalent if
>
> - they are declared in the same scope
> - they have the same name
> - they have identical template parameter lists
> - **the expressions involving template parameters in their return types and parameter lists are equivalent**

The case#1 works because the return type is dependent on the template parameter and used with different expression; then they're considered not equivalent.

Comment: @Klaus I fixed the statement. The point is *different expression*.

Comment: Thanks! So I keep in mind that the expression itself makes the difference. It feels strange that this expression is something like part of the signature... but ok, it is like it is;)